# Изменить код сторонней библиотеки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки

Скажите, пожалуйста, как открыть и изменить код установленной сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: Найти её в каталоге `<PYTHON_HOME>\Libs`, открыть текстовым редактором и изменить.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev в <PYTHON_HOME>\Lib нашел библиотеку. После редактирования ее нужно переустанавливать или нет?

Comment: Нет, переустанавливать не нужно.